# Updating h5py Datasets

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Does any one have an idea for updating hdf5 datasets from h5py?
Assuming we create a dataset like:

```
import h5py
import numpy
f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5')
dset = f.create_dataset('mydataset', data=numpy.ones((2,2),"=i4"))
new_dset_value=numpy.zeros((3,3),"=i4")
```

Is it possible to extend the dset to a 3x3 numpy array?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create the dataset with the "extendable" property. It's not possible to change this after the initial creation of the dataset. To do this, [you need to use the "maxshape" keyword](https://code.google.com/p/h5py/wiki/HowTo#Appending_to_a_dataset_%28HDF5_1.8_only%29). A value of `None` in the `maxshape` tuple means that that dimension can be of unlimited size. So, if `f` is an HDF5 file:

```
dset = f.create_dataset('mydataset', (2,2), maxshape=(None,3))
```

creates a dataset of size (2,2), which may be extended indefinitely along the first dimension and to 3 along the second.  Now, you can extend the dataset with `resize`:

```
dset.resize((3,3))
dset[:,:] = np.zeros((3,3),"=i4")
```

The first dimension can be increased as much as you like:

```
dset.resize((10,3))
```

Comment: resize also accepts an axis argument so you only have to specify the new size for the axis you're extending, rather than all of them:  dset.resize(10, axis=0)

Comment: That's very useful @velotron, it could be added to the accepted answer because for multidimensional arrays it is easier to do so.

Comment: does this example overwrite what was previously in the file? or does it just append the new contents?

Comment: You 'append' to the current data while you increase or decrease the size. The indexes of the data do not change when you resize a dataset. http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: As I was searching for it, If you want to resize a 1-dimentional array, you have to pass (None, ) to maxshape, don't forget to write , to make it a tuple.   Also do it in resize method or use axie=0 as Joseph mentioned.