# Adding or removing specific rows or columns in an h5py dataset

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Once you create an [h5py dataset](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html#quick), how do you add or remove specific rows or columns from an NxM array?

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213525/updating-h5py-datasets), but I don't want to blindly truncate or expand the array. When removing, I need to be able to specify the exact row or column to remove.

For adding, I know I have to specify `maxshape=(None, None)` when creating the initial dataset, but the [`resize`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html?highlight=resize#Dataset.resize) method doesn't seem to let you specify which rows or columns get truncated if you shrink the size.

Answer (score 7):

h5py isn't really designed for doing this. [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) might be a better library to use, as it's built around the concept of tables.

Having said that, here's how to do it:

```
In [1]: f = h5py.File('test.h5')

In [2]: arr = rand(4,4)

In [3]: dset = f.create_dataset('foo',data=arr,maxshape=(2000,2000))

In [4]: dset[:]
Out[4]:
array([[ 0.29732874,  0.59310285,  0.61116263,  0.79950116],
       [ 0.4194363 ,  0.4691813 ,  0.95648712,  0.56120731],
       [ 0.76868585,  0.07556214,  0.39854704,  0.73415885],
       [ 0.0919063 ,  0.0420656 ,  0.35082375,  0.62565894]])

In [5]: dset[1:-1,:] = dset[2:,:]

In [6]: dset.resize((3,4))

In [7]: dset[:]
Out[7]:
array([[ 0.29732874,  0.59310285,  0.61116263,  0.79950116],
       [ 0.76868585,  0.07556214,  0.39854704,  0.73415885],
       [ 0.0919063 ,  0.0420656 ,  0.35082375,  0.62565894]])
```

This removes column 1 from `dset`. It does so by assigning columns 2 and 3 to 1 and 2, respectively, before shrinking the dataset by one column. Swap the subscripts to remove row 1. You can easily write a wrapper around this if you're going to be doing it a lot.