# How to add data to H5py data?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I have created dataset with 4 names. and by default has only one value each.
How do I add another vaue to each group`'lstm_X'`

```
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('lstm_X', data=0)
h5f.create_dataset('lstm_Y', data=0)
h5f.create_dataset('lstm_X_test', data=0)
h5f.create_dataset('lstm_Y_test', data=0)
h5f.close()
```

Now I want my `h5f['lstm_X']= 0,1`

any ideas on to do this

Comment: after `h5f.close()` do `h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'a')`

Comment: You need to create the datasets as "extendable". See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213525/updating-h5py-datasets.